# Adding an int into middle of char* (In C)

Tags: c, char-pointer

Was wondering how it were possible to have an int in the middle of a char*, as such:

```
char * winning_message =
"Congratulations, you have finished the game with a score of " + INT_HERE +
"                 Press any key to exit...                   ";
```

Comment: `char *` + INT_HERE is valid. result is also `char *`. but `char *` + `char *` is invalid. So, It isn't  possible.

Comment: It might be ok in the sense that it would compile, but I don't think it would yield the behavior the questioner is trying to achieve.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It can not be compiled.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I was referring to the 'char * + INT_HERE', which, as you say, is valid, but as I say, doesn't yield the result the questioner wants (the resulting pointer would, at best, point to the end-part of the string, rather than to a string with an integer interposed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
char winning_message[128]; // make sure you have enough space!
sprintf(winning_message, "Congratulations, you have finished the game with a score of %i. Press any key to exit...", INT_HERE);
```

Comment: You should use snprintf if you use fixed length buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
char buf[256];  // make sure this is big enough to hold your entire string!
sprintf(buf, "Congratulations, you have finished the game with a score of %i\nPress any key to exit...", INT_HERE);
```

Note that the above is unsafe in the sense that if your string ends up being longer than sizeof(buf), sprintf() will write past the end of it and corrupt your stack.  To avoid that risk, you could call snprintf() instead:

```
char buf[256];  // make sure this is big enough to hold your entire string!
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Congratulations, you have finished the game with a score of %i\nPress any key to exit...", INT_HERE);
```

... the only downside is that snprintf() may not be available on every OS.

Comment: You should use snprintf if you use  fixed length buffers.

Comment: Yes, I covered that in my answer.

Comment: "`snprintf()` may not be available on every OS"-- note that `snprintf()` is a Standard Library function, and so must be available in any conforming implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
char * winning_message;
asprintf(&winning_message,"Congratulations, you have finished the game with a score of %d\nPress any key to exit...\n", INT_HERE);
```

Comment: Note that with asprintf() you will need to call free(winning_message) after you are done with the string, or else your program will leak memory.

Comment: `asprintf()` is not a Standard Library function, or even a POSIX funtion, but a compiler extension.

Comment: @DavidBowling library extension